# tf.estimator.export.build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn problem

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I have a problem about exporting a savedmodel from an estimator of Tensorflow. My tensorflow program is using an estimator to do the CNN function, where the input is a 2D image. This is my code for the saving part.

```
            def serving_input_rec_fn():
                serving_features = {'images': tf.placeholder(shape=[None, self.num_input[0], self.num_input[1]], dtype=tf.float32)}
                return tf.estimator.export.build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn(features=serving_features)

            self.model.export_savedmodel(export_dir, serving_input_rec_fn,
                                         strip_default_attrs=True)
```

But when I ran export_savedmodel function, it produced the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'features'
```

When I checked the code, I actually provided the serving_features here. Could any one help me solve this problem?

Comment: **IMPORTANT**: PLEASE ADD THE LANGUAGE TAG YOU ARE DEVELOPING IN. TENSORFLOW SUPPORTS MORE THAN ONE LANGUAGE.

Answer (score 0):

you miss a bracket in the argument 'serving_input_rec_fn' passed to export_savedmodel, the right way should be like:

```
self.model.export_savedmodel(export_dir, **serving_input_rec_fn()**, strip_default_attrs=True)
```

Because the export_savedmodel api require a 'serving_input_receiver_fn' function, while the value of 'serving_input_rec_fn' is a function: 'serving_input_rec_fn'. 
You need to call 'serving_input_rec_fn()' which returns tf.estimator.export.build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn(features=serving_features) which then returns a function: 'serving_input_receiver_fn'.

Answer (score 0):

In method `export_savedmodel()`,

change

**serving_input_rec_fn**

to

**serving_input_rec_fn()**

Answer (score 0):

In serving_input_rec_fn() change:

```
def serving_input_rec_fn():
   ...
   return tf.estimator.export.build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn(features=serving_features)
```

to:

```
def serving_input_rec_fn():
   ...
   return tf.estimator.export.build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn(serving_features)
```

As of documentation ([here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/export/build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn)), ***build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn*** function does not have a **features** argument

Answer (score 0):

it should be like

```py
def serving_input_rec_fn():
    ...
    tf.estimator.export.build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn(serving_features)()
```